# How can I customise navigation bar using XCode 9 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar

I can I customise navigation bar like this in Xcode 9.
I have no idea and I am doing in the XCode 9 storyboard.

[image: find the image here]

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot customize according to your size. But you can achieve navigation bar like behavior by following.

1. Hide navigationBar
2. Use Custom view in every controller
3. Create a single nib and add as subView.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this extension if you wanna hide it (transparent)

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```